# Make CircleBorder encapsulate the whole child widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a circular ElevatedButton, but stuck on a formatting problem: the size of the border seems to only take into account the height of the child widget, not the width. To illustrate, this:

```
return ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: CircleBorder(),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text(
    "I want the circle border\nto encapsulate all the text"
  ),
);
```

Produces this result:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to make the circular border go around the whole text, **without hard coding any fixed sizes or hacking it by using padding**, because I want it to be responsive to changes in text content and size. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to use `StadiumBorder()` instead?

Comment: `StadiumBorder` looks interesting, I hadn't come across that one before so thanks, but I would prefer to have a circular border if possible. I'm thinking that I need to make the child widget square somehow. I'm playing around with `AspectRatio` but that seems to make the button expand to fill all available space of it's parent, which isn't what I want either :(

Comment: *"[...] but I would prefer to have a circular border if possible"* - so it seems you need a custom `ShapeBorder` / `OutlinedBorder` - see how `CircleBorder` creates its shape: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7e9793dee1/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/circle_border.dart#L60 - here `rect.shortestSide` is used

Comment: Do you want a circle as button?

Comment: Thanks @pskink you got me on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @pskink the solution was to tweak CircleBorder to use the longest side insead of shortest side when drawing the border path. Here it is:

[image]

```
class EncapsulatingCircularBorder extends OutlinedBorder {
  /// Create a circle border.
  ///
  /// The [side] argument must not be null.
  const EncapsulatingCircularBorder({ BorderSide side = BorderSide.none }) : assert(side != null), super(side: side);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    return EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => EncapsulatingCircularBorder(side: side.scale(t));

  @override
  ShapeBorder? lerpFrom(ShapeBorder? a, double t) {
    if (a is EncapsulatingCircularBorder)
      return EncapsulatingCircularBorder(side: BorderSide.lerp(a.side, side, t));
    return super.lerpFrom(a, t);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder? lerpTo(ShapeBorder? b, double t) {
    if (b is EncapsulatingCircularBorder)
      return EncapsulatingCircularBorder(side: BorderSide.lerp(side, b.side, t));
    return super.lerpTo(b, t);
  }

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, { TextDirection? textDirection }) {

    return Path()
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
        center: rect.center,
        // Changed this from rect.shortestSide to longestSide
        radius: math.max(0.0, rect.longestSide / 2.0 - side.width),
      ));
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, { TextDirection? textDirection }) {

    return Path()
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
        center: rect.center,
        // Changed this from rect.shortestSide to longestSide
        radius: rect.longestSide / 2.0,
      ));
  }

  @override
  EncapsulatingCircularBorder copyWith({ BorderSide? side }) {
    return EncapsulatingCircularBorder(side: side ?? this.side);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, { TextDirection? textDirection }) {
    switch (side.style) {
      case BorderStyle.none:
        break;
      case BorderStyle.solid:
        canvas.drawCircle(rect.center, (rect.shortestSide - side.width) / 2.0, side.toPaint());
    }
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
    return other is EncapsulatingCircularBorder
        && other.side == side;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => side.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${objectRuntimeType(this, 'EncapsulatingCircularBorder')}($side)';
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, you need to change `shortestSide` in `paint` method too, note you dont need to implement methods like `lerp*` if you dont need to morph your shape

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: A circle border is a strict requirement, so the answer is updated for the same.

Using a `FloatingActionButton` gets the work done

```
SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text("I want the circle border\nto encapsulate all the text"),
      ),
    );
```

SizedBox is necessary to give button the size.

[image]

**Old Answer**

Adding `StadiumBorder()` will solve your issue.

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: StadiumBorder(),
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
        "I want the circle border\nto encapsulate all the text"
      ),
    );
```

[image: How the button looks]

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to have a circular border if possible